# Faces message stops working after page navigation

Tags: jsf, primefaces, portlet

I have a problem with faces message rendering in portlet, deployed on HCL portal 9.5, which is on top of Websphere Application Server 9.0.5.7. Portlet has two pages and when I made first page navigation, faces message stops rendering.

First page html:

```
<div xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:portlet="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event listener="#{pc_TestJSF22View.init}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:head>
        <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="formMain" styleClass="form">
            <p:commandButton id="btnTest" value="Test"
                action="#{pc_TestJSF22View.doBtnTest}" />
            <p:commandButton id="btnSecondPage" value="Second page"
                action="#{pc_TestJSF22View.doBtnSecondPage}" ajax="false" />

            <p:messages id="msgGlobal" globalOnly="true" showIcon="false">
                <p:autoUpdate />
            </p:messages>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

First page request bean:

```
public class TestJSF22View extends PageCodeBase {

private TestSess testSess;

public void init() {
    if (PrimeFaces.current().isAjaxRequest()) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        System.out.println("INIT method");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

// button action
 public String doBtnSecondPage() {
     return "testView2";
 }

public String doBtnTest() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("page 1 msg updated"));
    return null;
}

protected TestSess getTestSess() {
    if (testSess == null) {
        testSess = (TestSess) getManagedBean("testSess");
    }
    return testSess;
}
```

}

Second page html:

```
<div xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:portlet="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event listener="#{pc_TestJSF22View2.init}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:head>
        <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="formMain" styleClass="form">
            <p:commandButton id="btnFirstPage" value="First page"
                action="#{pc_TestJSF22View2.doBtnFirstPage}" ajax="false" />

            <p:commandButton id="btnMsg" value="Show message"
                action="#{pc_TestJSF22View2.doBtnMsg}" />

            <p:messages id="msgGlobal2" globalOnly="true" showIcon="false">
                <p:autoUpdate />
            </p:messages>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

Second page request bean:

```
public class TestJSF22View2 extends PageCodeBase {
private TestSess2 testSess2;

public void init() {
    if (PrimeFaces.current().isAjaxRequest()) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        System.out.println("INIT2 method");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

// button action

public String doBtnFirstPage() {
    System.out.println("doBtnFirstPage method");
    return "testView";
}

public String doBtnMsg() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("page 2 msg updated"));
    return null;
}

protected TestSess2 getTestSess2() {
    if (testSess2 == null) {
        testSess2 = (TestSess2) getManagedBean("testSess2");
    }
    return testSess2;
}
```

}

faces-config :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <application>
        <view-handler>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FaceletPortletViewHandler</view-handler>
        <el-resolver>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.PortletELResolver</el-resolver>
        <resource-handler>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.httpbridge.PortletResourceHandler</resource-handler>
    </application>
    <factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
    </factory>
    <component>
        <component-type>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.component.PortletActionURL</component-type>
        <component-class>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.component.PortletActionURL</component-class>
    </component>
    <component>
        <component-type>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.component.PortletResourceURL</component-type>
        <component-class>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.component.PortletResourceURL</component-class>
    </component>
    <component>
        <component-type>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.component.PortletRenderURL</component-type>
        <component-class>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.component.PortletRenderURL</component-class>
    </component>
    <component>
        <component-type>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.component.PortletParam</component-type>
        <component-class>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.component.PortletParam</component-class>
    </component>
    <component>
        <component-type>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.component.PortletProperty</component-type>
        <component-class>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.component.PortletProperty</component-class>
    </component>
    <component>
        <component-type>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.component.PortletNameSpace</component-type>
        <component-class>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.component.PortletNameSpace</component-class>
    </component>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>pc_TestJSF22View</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>pagecode.TestJSF22View</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>testSess</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>beans.TestSess</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>pc_TestJSF22View2</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>pagecode.TestJSF22View2</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>testSess2</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>beans.TestSess2</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
            <renderer-type>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.tag.render.ActionURLTagRender</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.tag.render.ActionURLTagRender</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>
    <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
            <renderer-type>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.tag.render.ResourceURLTagRender</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.tag.render.ResourceURLTagRender</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>
    <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
            <renderer-type>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.tag.render.RenderURLTagRender</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.tag.render.RenderURLTagRender</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>
    <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
            <renderer-type>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.tag.render.PortletNameSpaceTagRender</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.tag.render.PortletNameSpaceTagRender</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>testView</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/TestJSF22View.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>testView2</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/TestJSF22View2.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

So, if I illustrate my problem: When I first open portlet and first page is displayed, I click "Test" button, that displays faces message. Next, I navigate to second page and I click "Show message" button, which should display another message on second page, but it doesn't. I get the following warning:

```
There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered.
These unhandled FacesMessages are: 
- page 2 msg updated
```

Even if I go back to the first page again and hit "Test" button one more time, message is not displayed and the same warning is what I get.

I never had problems with faces messages when I deployed portlets on IBM Websphere Portal Server 7 with JSF 2.0, but now when I run it on HCL portal 9.5 (JSF 2.2), I noticed this strange behavior.

Did I miss something while migrating to HCL portal?

Primefaces version is 7.0, `p:messages` usage seems ok to me. Could HCL portlet bridge cause that problem? Does anyone have experience with deploying JSF portlets on HCL Portal?

EDIT1:
I've just tried to deploy web application with identical code on Websphere Application Server 9 and it works like a charm. Based on that I believe there's some problem with HCL Portal.

Comment: That warning means that Your message was added but that content was already rendered or the buffer was closed so Faces gives you that warning saying it did not render the message. I have seen this when messages are added in a Phase like RENDER_RESPONSE or later in the JSF LifeCycle.

Comment: @Melloware I understand that but it renders message on the first page without any problem before I visit second page. It doesn't make any sense to me. Also I've tried to deploy web app with identical code on Websphere Application Server 9 and it works.